# put file on ftp server in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know how to get a file from a ftp server, with the method dataWithContentsOfURL. Now I want a put a file on the ftp server, how I can do this?

Comment: Note that FTP is an awful protocol to use.  Inefficient and, worse, grossly insecure in all but the most carefully configured circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

[ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit)

NSOutputStream's `-initWithURL:` might also let you do this.